# Author numbers are the same for different authors with same affiliation

Tags: author-number

I am using `\documentclass[<options>]{elsarticle}` and have used `\author[1]{Author 1}`,
`\author[2]{Author 2}`,`\address{Department of Mathematics}` but that gives me the same number on the authors as shown below. Is this because they are of the same affiliation (aka same address)? May I know how I can get different numbers of symbols on the two authors then? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I have briefly looked at the `elsarticle` manual and, being a GOM, found it dificult to understand regarding authors. However if the author footnotes correspond to their affiliialtions it seems sensible to me that the same affiliation should have the same footnote. You want different footnote numbers but waht are they to be reffered to?

Comment: @PeterWilson Thanks, I wasn't sure if same affiliation normally results in same footnote. That makes sense.